# Force close error on setOnClickListener (Example from hello Android book section 3.5)

Tags: android, onclicklistener, forceclose

I am having problem in starting a new activity on clicking a button, here's my code:

```
package test.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

  View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_content);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.about_content:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, testit.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        // More buttons go here (if any) ...
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me correct this error

Error Line

```
aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click here" android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="Click here" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

XML file containing about_content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text" />
</ScrollView>
```

about_content is already defined here

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about_text" />
```

Comment: while binding your button you need to bind in this pattern if it is declared in xml..  Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

Comment: Again, the "XML file containing about_content" must be in the layout passed to setContentView() otherwise `findViewById(R.id.about_content)` will return null, because `about_content` does not exist in this context.

Comment: Did you declare your `testit.class` in manifest file?

Comment: @tai.tran2008: yes I have declared testit activity in manifest.xml

Comment: Let's say the ScrollView and the TextView are in a file called scroll_content.xml, try this: `setContentView(R.layout.scroll_content);` instead of `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you didn't post your logcat output, but since this is such a common beginner's mistake, I'm going to take a wild guess and say that you are probably getting a `NullPointerException`.

Your call to `findViewById` is probably returning `null`, which means that the system could not find the view associated with the id given by `R.id.about_content`. I would double check your XML layout for typos.

Comment: Sir i have posted my XML files.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, but `about_content` does not exist in this XML file, and thus, it is not found. You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.about_content_xml_file)`.

Comment: What I want is after clicking on Button in main.xml will open a new view of testfor.xml file.

Comment: Then change `findViewById(R.id.about_content);` to `findViewById(R.id.button1)`.

Comment: Don't forget to click the empty check by the side of the answer if it helped you out :).

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you don't have anything with the id `about_content` in main.xml, which will create a NullPointerException.

Also, if `aboutButton` is supposed to be a traditional Button, then you should use this:

```
Button aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about_content);
```

**Addition**

Since `aboutButton` is a TextView, use this:

```
TextView aboutButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.about_content);
```

but this TextView *must* be in the layout passed to setContentView() or findViewById() will return null.

Comment: about_content is a text view ID in another layout XML file

Comment: findViewById() can only find views in the current xml file, in this case main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the "main.xml" which you have set your content view ... does not contain the about_content TextView, its in the other xml which you have posted ...

Note: You can access only those R.id's which are present in your setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout) xml ...

Answer (score 0):

you make `setContentView(R.layout.main);` but `main.xml` does not include View have id =  `R.id.about_content`. If you raplace by `findViewById(R.id.button1);` It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for

```
Button aboutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about_content);
```

And dont forget to add `testit Activity in Android Manifest`